# Laravel 5.8 require function in app.js not found

Tags: jquery, laravel, charts

I'm trying to add a chart in my Laravel frontend application.

1. In app.js I added `require('./horizBarChart');`
2. In app.scss I added `@import 'horizBarChart.scss';`
3. After app.js I added the function call method (and a jQuery test, that works):
   [image]

Now, after compiling I see that the horizBarChart function is included in my app.js generated file:
[image]

But when opening the website I still get funtion not found error:
[image]

If I dont use require but include it as basic `<script src="../jquery.horizBarChart.min.js"></script>` all works fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove image, Please add `code` in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link` tag in HTML is used for css, for `scripts` it should be:

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

And also I think you should put this line below jQuery, not above as I see the library also uses jQuery, so make sure that jQuery is loaded first.

Comment: Good point. Also, if your horizBarChart is a jquery plugin then you must put it below the jquery core

Comment: Oh lol, how did that happen. Thank you :D I was wondering why the standard jquery in app.js was not working >.<

Answer (score 0):

JS file `"app.js"` You've included in **Style/CSS/Link** Tag, You need to include in **Script** Tag:

[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzXYp.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Make your directory structure is like this for JS: `/public/js/app.js`